# O que são funções built-in? E qual é sua diferença de palavras reservadas?

Tags: python

Faz pouco tempo que comecei a estudar a linguagem Python e no meio dos estudos surgiu uma dúvida. O que são funções *built-in*? E qual sua diferença de palavras reservadas? Fiquei confuso com essa questão, pois pra mim parece ser iguais. Estou correto? Peço desculpas caso esteja falando bobagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muito boa questão - vamos colocar assim:

Python busca ser uma linguagem elegante. Nesse sentido, as palavras chave da linguagem são o que possibilitam a sua mecânica: condicionais com "if", "elif" e "else", estruturas de laço com "for" e "while", definição de funções com "def" e tipos com "class", associação de nomes com objetos (o mesmo efeito que "atribuição de valores a variáveis") com o operador "=" e assim por diante.

Esses efeitos, tendo dados com os quais trabalhar, permitem que se crie qualquer programa - mas perceba o seguinte: nenhum deles "obtêm" dados de nenhuma forma de entrada, nem escreve dados para nenhum lugar.  Esses são os mecanismos da linguagem em si. (Na versão "2" do Python havia uma exceção que era o comando "print", uma palavra reservada que tinha o efeito colateral de colocar dados na saída - fosse no terminal, ou em um arquivo) - Ou seja, toda a "lógica" essencial da linguagem está nas palavras chave (mesmo que não pareçam palavras chave, como o operador "=").

Agora, qualquer programa, para ter algum efeito no ambiente em que está em execução, precisa interagir com o sistema de alguma forma - seja lendo e escrevendo em arquivos, na tela - e também é interessante ter outras utilidades como saber o comprimento de sequências, criar sequências e novos tipos - enfim, coisas que são ferramentas mais ou menos universais para o programa poder "fazer algo". O pessoal do Python percebeu ao longo da própria evolução da linguagem que ter essas ferramentas prontamente disponíveis, sem precisar importar nenhuma biblioteca ou módulo, facilitava sobremaneira executar tarefas completas. Mas todas essas comunicações são feitas, em algum nível com o sistema operacional, e podem ser encapsuladas numa função - que para quem está escrevendo um programa, é idêntica em importância a qualquer função que o programador mesmo crie.

Então foram surgindo essas funções que estão sempre disponíveis, mesmo que não se importe nenhum pacote ou módulo da biblioteca padrão: o `print` (no Python 3, ele passa ao status de função), `input`, `open` para abrir um arquivo, `len`, `max`, `min`, `type`, `range` dentre outros.  Essas são algumas das funções built-in - e a única diferença delas para qualquer outra função é que estão disponíveis automaticamente em qualquer módulo ou contexto.

A listagem completa das mesmas está aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

A existência dessas funções (e outras variáveis) built-in é o que torna possível em Python, ter um programa que abre um arquivo para escrita e grava algum conteúdo no mesmo em uma única linha - enquanto que em Java, por exemplo,, a mesma operação -  que é uma das coisas mais fundamentais para um programa: interagir com o ambiente - isso requer a importação de duas classes de módulos distintos, e criação de uma instância das mesmas - apenas para começar a interagir com o arquivo - e a documentação para achar essas classes sequer é trivial de achar. Em Python isso requer apenas `open("meuarq.txt").write("Alô mundo!")` -  o `open` é uma built-in.

Agora, a história não termina aí: Python tem um design bem interessante e consistente de busca de nomes de funções e variáveis - que dá ao programador controle completo sobre o que "existe" num determinado escopo do programa. O mecanismo completo é mais ou menos esse: ao encontrar um nome de função (ou outro objeto), o runtime do Python verifica primeiro se aquele nome existe nas variáveis locais (dentro da função em execução, por exemplo). Senão existir, ele busca nas variáveis "globais" - que são globais em um módulo - em geral nomes de funções e classes definidos pelo programador ficam nesse escopo. Se o nome não é encontrado em nenhum desses dois lugares, o Python faz a busca no módulo `__builtins__` - onde estão definidas todas essas funções.

Isso permite, por exemplo, que para fins de testes, brincadeiras, ou até modificação temporaria do comportamento de uma função real, você altere o valor de uma função "built-in"   simplesmente criando uma outra função com o mesmo nome.  A função será criada como uma variável global ou local, e pode ser usada normalmente - até ser excluida, por exemplo, com o comando "del" - nesse ponto, a definição original em `__builtins__` volta a ser usada.

Isso permite por exemplo, que se escreva código que funcione ao mesmo tempo em Python 2.7 e 3.X, redefinindo-se no começo do módulo o nome "input" para ser "raw_input" se estivermos em Python 2 - aí seu programa pode usar o "input" e funcionar normalmente em Python 2 - mas usando já o nome moderno da função:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

if sys.version[0] < 3:
    input = raw_input

# Restante do programa
```

(Como o print do Python 2 é um comando, a sintaxe especial `from __future__ import print_function` é necessária para trazer o print como função, equivalente ao Python 3, para um programa em Python 2. Mas a simples atribuição `input = raw_input` troca o input com "eval" do Python 2 pelo "raw_input" que sempre lê uma string, como o `input` do Python 3.

(E, sim, também é possível trocar o significado de uma função  "builtin" alterando diretamente o nome em  `__builtins__` - isso vai fazer a substituição em todos os módulos do programa - mas aí você perde o controle da situação - não se recomenda faze-lo)

Comment: Cara sensacional sua explicação muito boa! Obrigado esclareceu minhas dúvidas.